# Need help with start mining: I am getting stuck with ? mark ( New work: header #2ef2a542?)

Tags: ethminer

I have referred to other information found on web to start on mining, but now I am stuck where it is about to begin to mine.

What is this mean when I try to use ethminer? It displays "New work: header" and gets stuck. What do I need to do here? Please see below

```
 i  16:47:32|main      Found suitable OpenCL device [ GeForce GTX 1080 Ti ] with 11811160064  bytes of GPU memory
 cl  16:47:32|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
  m  16:47:32|main      Waiting for work package...
  m  16:47:32|main      Got work package: #2ef2a542
  m  16:47:33|main      Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  16:47:34|main      Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  16:47:35|main      Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
 cl  16:47:35|cl-0      New work: header #2ef2a542?
```